# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore" on latest MacOS

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I'm trying to decrease the compilation time for my cloud_firestore app but I can't seem to run pod install. I run a relatively old MacBook Air to compile my iOS builds and currently it takes over 30 minutes to build. You can see how unproductive it is.

I get the following error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":
  In Podfile:
    FirebaseFirestore (from `https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`, tag `8.15.0`)

    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 4.13.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (= 10.18.0) was resolved to 10.18.0, which depends on
        FirebaseFirestore (~> 10.18.0)
```

Here's part of my Podfile:

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

Here's my pubspec:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.0 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  shared_preferences: ^2.0.20
  provider: ^6.0.5
  numberpicker: ^2.1.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^16.1.0
  notification_permissions: ^0.6.1
  configurable_expansion_tile_null_safety: 3.3.1
  firebase_core: ^2.22.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.13.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.4.4
  cloud_firestore: ^4.13.2
  firebase_analytics: ^10.6.4
  firebase_app_check: ^0.2.1+4
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  xml: ^6.3.0
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.2
  googleapis_auth: ^1.4.0
  googleapis: ^11.4.0
  package_info_plus: ^5.0.1
  devicelocale: 0.7.0
  flutter_email_sender: ^6.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.12
  connectivity_plus: ^5.0.1
  auto_size_text: 3.0.0
  purchases_flutter: 6.3.0
  modal_progress_hud_alt: 1.0.0

  intl: ^0.18.0 #0.17.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

And I'm physically tired of deleting podfile.lock, pods and any other possible file/folder, doing flutter cleans and pod repo updates and installs with no success for two days.

I'm running Flutter 3.16.0, Xcode 15.0.1, Sonoma 14.1.1, cocoapods 1.14.3

That said, I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the tag specifier in the Podfile from 8.15.0 to 10.18.0:

`pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.18.0'`

Comment: You're a life saver!!! Care to explain how do we know which version to use? I just followed the documentation.

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason not to, it's recommended to use the latest release, which is shown in the Releases section at https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting `Podfile.lock` and `Pods folder` then run `pod install` command

Comment: Tried that and much more. I've even tried deleting the iOS folder.

Comment: Try changing `platform :ios, '13.0'`  in Podfile

Comment: I'm already using platform :ios, '13.0' :/